# Not enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives/

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, apt

I attempted to install the texlive package, but it could not finish the installation properly. When I then tried to continue on, it almost finished installing everything, but the texlive-publishers-doc couldn't be installed due to there not being enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives/. As a result, now I cannot install or delete any package, because this error appears, and neither can I execute `sudo apt-get autoremove`, or `sudo apt-get update`.

I've executed `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`, but after them the problem is still there.

I've been searching online for an answer, but, even though it's happened to some people, none of the solutions I found online have worked. I'm running out of ideas before reinstalling.

By the way, I'm using Linux Mint 19 (Tara) Cinnamon 64-bit, in dual booting with Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to give apt a bit of breathing space - you can do this by removing all .deb files from `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Next step is to `apt -f install`, putting the packet manager into a consistent state. Finally `apt autoremove` will most likely remove a lot of old kernel images, in the process fixing the space problem for good.

You should the make a habit of running `apt autoremove` regularily, either manual or by configuring your unattended-upgrades in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` to include this step.

Comment: There are no .deb files in that directory right now.

Also, apt -f install does not do anything, and autoremove is unable to work because:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-full : Depends: texlive-publishers-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not installed

Which is the package which I cannot install because I have no space in cache.

Answer (score 2):

@Atalajaka the following error "The following packages have unmet dependencies: texlive-full : Depends: texlive-publishers-doc (>= 2017.20170628)" means that you had an error of unmet dependencies when you installed a certain package wich requires textlive dependencie, this caused an error in apt cache, to resolve this problem :

1- Browse to the folder where you executed the command 'dpkg -i [package name-xx].deb'

2- remove the package by typing :

```
dpkg -r [packagename]
```